SSL handshake failed when connecting to Mongodb Atlas from ECS Fargate
An error is output when connecting from ECS Fargate to Mongodb Atlas.
error occured: SSL handshake failed: ac-xvafg1z-shard-00-00.pizmgb2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1007) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),SSL handshake failed: ac-xvafg1z-shard-00-02.pizmgb2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1007) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),SSL handshake failed: ac-xvafg1z-shard-00-01.pizmgb2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1007) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 669fb320b2ab667661629f2f, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-xvafg1z-shard-00-00.pizmgb2.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-xvafg1z-shard-00-00.pizmgb2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1007) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-xvafg1z-shard-00-01.pizmgb2.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-xvafg1z-shard-00-01.pizmgb2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1007) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-xvafg1z-shard-00-02.pizmgb2.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-xvafg1z-shard-00-02.pizmgb2.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1007) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>


I am using pymongo.
driver_URL=mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@<domain>/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0

    with MongoClient(driver_URL) as client :
        webcamDb = client.webcam
        webCamCol = webcamDb.webcam

I don't know how to fix it.
Please help.

Add public IP to ECS  and add 0.0.0.0/0 to Network White List of MongoDB Atlas.
It works...
